# Regenerate table in googlesheets using python

Tags: python

I am trying to find/work out the code needed to get a table of sales data to regenerate at the beginning of each sales day using googlesheets and python3. I've been combing the web and youtube but not had any luck yet. Any advice would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Is the above the right sort of question to write on this platform?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.